# Is there way to get notifications from Google Play Developer Console about delivery of updates of APK?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-developer-api

I want to get notifications about ending period of accepting and updating of my application from Google Play Console, but I didn't find any way to get them. Is there way to get notifications from Google Play Developer Console about delivery of updates of APK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there way to get notifications from Google Play Developer Console
>   about delivery of updates of APK?

No, as of today there is no official way to get alerts for updates processing or delivery. I've been waiting for long to have this.

Amazon and Samsung stores have decent notifying mechanisms for change is status It would be good to have it in Google Play too.

Comment: Thanks for answer. It is very bad for us =(